# Python Brute Forcer?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I had a general idea in mind for a way to brute force a password, but being just a python novice, i'm not sure where to go from here...

So far I have the following:

```
password = "myPaSs123"

ll = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
ul = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
n = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
s = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&"]
full = ll+ul+n+s
crackedPass = []

def guesser():
    guess = 0
    for i in full:
        for x in range(len(password)):
            if i == password:
                crackedPass.append(i)
                print "Password found: " + str(crackedPass)

guesser()
```

I now have no clue what to do from here. If someone has some insight to this topic, I would love any help. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you work your way through your code, line by line, and [explain it to a rubber duck](http://www.rubberduckdebugging.com/). You should be able to see relatively quickly where you're going wrong.

Comment: Also, have a look at the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module, it'll save you some typing in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this but will NOT be efficient:

```
def all_combinations_with_len(lst,min_len,max_len):
    for i in xrange(min_len,max_len+1):
         for j in list(itertools.product(*([lst]*i))):
            yield j
```

Then you can use:

```
list(all_combinations_with_len(['a','b','c'],2,5))
```

[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c')]

Or:

```
for i in combinations_with_replacement_max_len(full,1,SOME_NUMBER):
    password = ''.join(i)
    compare_password_and_other_stuff(password)
```

Bear in mind that THIS IS NOT how passwords are cracked and expect long running times for large SOME_NUMBER.

Comment: ahh yes - this is where a quantum computer is useful, as the correct combination will magically appear in an instant...

Answer (score -1):

This is what you wanted i belive, the problem is im just giving you answer for your problem and i belive you do not understand this code i have posted so let me explain in great detail!
Your code is ok but is just nasty in terms of reading this code i have posted is what you wanted to achieve but with a greater understanding of what you wanted to do...

> (1st) we import the functions: itertools, math, and os

They give us a great amount of function for use in the program...
Then we have the alphabet which is simple enough it contains the alphabet or chars as i like to call them since they are chars after all.

The rest is up to you to read this is not a tutorial but reading through what i have gave you should give the lines to color in behind happy coding brother's/sister's !

```
import itertools, math
import os
Alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890") # Add or     remove whatevs you think will be in the password you're cracking (example, [symbols])
counter = 1
CharLength = 1
range_num = int(raw_input("Enter range: "))
stopper = range_num + 1
filename = "bruteforce_%r.txt" % (range_num)
f = open(filename, 'a')
#n_1 = len(Alphabet)
#n_2 = n_1 - 1 # <-- total useless peice of garbage that could of been great in vurtual life
#n_3 = '0' * n_2
#n = '1' + n_3
x = range_num
y = len(Alphabet)
amount = math.pow(y, x)
total_items = math.pow(y, x)
for CharLength in range(range_num, stopper):
    passwords = (itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat = CharLength))

    for i in passwords:
        counter += 1
        percentage = (counter / total_items) * 100
        amount -= 1
        i = str(i)
        i = i.replace("[", "")
        i = i.replace("]", "")
        i = i.replace("'", "")
        i = i.replace(" ", "")
        i = i.replace(",", "")
        i = i.replace("(", "")
        i = i.replace(")", "")
        f.write(i)
        f.write('\n')
        print "Password: %r\tPercentage: %r/100\tAmount left: %r" % (i, int(percentage), amount)
        if i == '0'* range_num:
            print "*Done"
            f.close()
            exit(0)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I will do so now brother ;)